# jQuery ScrollTo plugin - horizontal scrolling

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I hope this is an appropriate question to post here. It's more a theory question rather than a specific coding problem.

I'm using the **[scrollTo plugin](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo)** by Ariel Flesler to create a horizontal scrolling webpage. All good, I've managed to download a working demo from a [tutorial site](http://www.arvindandrion.com/2009/09/horizontal-scroll-using-jquery-scrollto/) ... except I don't understand the theory behind horizontal scrolling.

In particular, most of the tutorials I've come across (as well as answers here on StackOverflow) suggest creating a HTML wrapper element which seems to act as a 'viewport' and scrolling the content within the wrapper (nested  tags for example) using scrollTo plugin.

Why can't I just position some  tags off-screen (say, 3000px to the right) and use scrollTo to horizontally scroll to these  tags?

I tried this and it works but I can't achieve a smooth scroll with easing (see code below).

Would appreciate it if someone could give me some insight into this.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>scrollTo Test</title>

<style>

#box {
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   background-color:#F00;
   position:relative;
   top:0;
   left:3000px;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<nav>
   <a href="#">CLICK</a>
</nav>

<div id="box">BOX</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>

$('nav a').on("click", function () {

    //$.scrollTo( '#box', {top:0 , left:800}, {easing:'easeOutElastic'} );
    $.scrollTo( '#box', 800, {easing:'easeOutElastic', axis:'x'} ); 

});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE:
I created a JSFiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/wzd8202a/

Comment: Can you provide any fiddle for what you have tried??

Comment: Seems to me it's caused by your easing method. [Using linear](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/wzd8202a/2/) works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the creator of the scrollTo plugin.
You should create a demo of this using something like jsfiddle, then I can fix it and share it.

EDIT: Well that works, are you referring to the fact it doesn't bounce correctly? If so, that's because nor the window nor other elements can scroll beyond their size. You need to leave a margin after the element for that.

In your example, I set a larger width to the body:

`body { width:4000px; }`

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/wzd8202a/3/) is a modified version that bounces correctly.

Let me know if that was it.

Comment: Ariel, many thanks for your help. I see my mistake.    But, in general, I'd like to know why a lot of scrollTo demos scroll a <div> tag inside a parent <div> tag? Why not just scroll within browser window like I've done here?

Comment: Both are done, you can do whichever you prefer. There's no advantage depends on your needs.